# Homestead + Laravel 5.1 + Debugbar: ports issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, homestead

I'm testing the Debugbar in Laravel 5.1, I'm new to Laravel so I'm following a book (Easy Laravel 5.1). I'm using Homestead, I got Laravel running, the Debugbar is showing up fine, I cand send messages to it, but in the Queries tab I get the following:

```
Exception
Cannot add listen to Queries for Laravel Debugbar: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/LaravelDebugbar.php#316

PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
/home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#50
```

My database configuration gets it from the ENV file, and it's correctly set up I think (when I use artisan to make models with migrations and then execute them, the database is updated fine).

I'm using localhost:33060 as the host in the ENV file. If I change the port to 3306, the Debugbar exceptions disappear, but I can't connect to the database from my app.

What could be the problem here? Thanks in advance!